# How to upload a new version for document use alfresco restfull api?

Tags: java, alfresco

I want upload a file to alfresco and I want to  create a new version if the file was exists in alfresco. How can i do it. I saw the alfresco api :"/alfresco/service/api/upload" has a parameter "majorversion", Can I use it or has another way?
  Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using it? Does it do what you want? Or do you need full control over the next version number?

Comment: Yes, I tried it.I set it true or like "2.0". But it doesn't work. I don't know how to use this parameter.

Comment: What do you mean by "Doesn't work"? Doesn't upload? Uploads but gives error? Uploads but doesn't create a new version?

Comment: Uploads but doesn't create a new version. I had resolve this problem. It must be set 'updatenoderef' parameter and can create a new version.

Answer (score 0):

As per your questioning, it seems you want to update a file and you want to keep older versions also.

If it is so then you need to do *check-out* the file and it will create private working copy *(PWC)*. Then do *check-in* operation for newly created PWC file.